# iOS - Trying to retrieve what the current font size of a label is set to

Tags: cocoa-touch, uilabel, font-size

I'm trying to find a way to programmatically retrieve the current font size of a label.  Something like this:

```
int sizeFont = myLabel.font.labelFontSize;
```

I know about how to retrieve the point size:

```
int sizePoint = myLabel.font.pointSize;
```

Looking for the font size.  Thanks for any help!

Here is where the label is initialized called from `-(void)viewDidLoad` a lot of other code is stripped out for readability

```
-(void)initializeUIElements
{
    // create a new UIView
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

    // initializing close scroll label
    close_scroll = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(258, 155, 70, 30)];
    close_scroll.text = @"Close Scroll";
    close_scroll.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(240/255.0) blue:(5/255.0) alpha:1];
    close_scroll.font = [UIFont fontWithName:user.display_font size:10];
    close_scroll.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159265358979323846264338327950288 * 1.5);
    [newView addSubview:close_scroll];

    // add the new view as a subview to the superview
    [self.view addSubview:newView];
}
```

** **this is called to update the font for the label.  The idea being that the user could come back from a profile configuration screen with a different font type selected.  The font is selected fine, just the size gets screwy.**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGFloat test2 = close_scroll.font.pointSize;

    // updating fonts displayed in case of a profile change
    close_scroll.font = [UIFont fontWithName:user.display_font size:test2];
}
```

Comment: The point size **is** the font size?

Comment: `pointSize` **is** the font size.

Comment: when I do a `int test1 = myLabel.font.pointSize;` on a label I know has been set to font size 10 I get back a value of 24....am I doing something wrong?

Comment: for your kind information, `myLabel.font.pointSize` and `myLabel.font.labelFontSize` are both `CGFloat` values, not `int`

Comment: thanks, wasn't getting a compiler warning?

Comment: show us how you are setting the fontsize. Your approach should be working, even with an int-variable.

Comment: FYI: `.labelFontSize` is an unknown property, which is why I was looking for the proper syntax.

Comment: labelfontsize is a class-method. it doesnt work like that. Use label.font.pointsize. Also, read the docs on UIFont.

Comment: additional code posted showing the actual use

Comment: From the docs: An affine transformation is a special type of mapping that preserves parallel lines in a path but does not necessarily preserve lengths or angles.  - So maybe your AffineTransformMakeRotation screws up your font? have you tried reversing the order of the two calls?

Comment: the transform is done during the label initialization and there appears to be no problems with it at that point.  It only seems to have a problem when I reenter the view controller and call `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` and try and get the current font size for the label.  That's where the font size seems to return a bad value.  I get a value back (24), it just isn't what the label is supposed to be set to (10).

Comment: what does NSLog(@"%f", [UIFont labelFontSize]); put out?

Comment: what is the syntax for querying a specific label? aka: `NSLog(@"%f",  close_scroll [UIFont labelFontSize]);`

Comment: for this `NSLog(@"%f", close_scroll.font.pointSize);` the result is "2013-02-20 09:02:33.643 TopicMemorizer[9260:c07] 24.000000", supposed to be 10

Answer (score 3):

ok, I figured it out.  Thanks to everyone who helped.  Evidentially, the custom font name I had coming into the routine was bad.  So the display defaulted to some system default size without throwing any errors.  The below line will work to retrieve a label's current font size.

```
// if you want to retrieve the font size as a separate value, this will work
int sizeLabelFont = labelOpenScroll.font.pointSize;

// this is actually how I am using the line
labelOpenScroll.font = [UIFont fontWithName:user.display_font size:labelOpenScroll.font.pointSize];
```